# Fill parent div height

Tags: css

So. we have 3 div's in my example. Main div is a container and next two are child's. So i would like to know how to extend container more than 100% height of window ( by using auto), and  fill the height by 2nd child ( 100% wont work)

Any help will be like appropriate

```css
#main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background-color: orange;
}

#nr1 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 1500px;
}

#nr2 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="nr1"> </div>
  <div id="nr2"> </div>

</div>
```

flexbox?!
 If i will ad a div on top with 100% width and 200 px height, wont fit...
Thats why it cant be a flaxbox - https://jsfiddle.net/pgd5mckx/

Comment: Have you tried set #main min-height: 100vh?

Comment: vh is the virtual height of the window (rather the height of the viewport) so that won't work @A.Meshu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flexbox` and specifically `flex-grow` to have the child div grow to fill the parents height. Below is the modification working as intended:

HTML

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="nr1"> </div>
  <div id="nr2"> </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: orange;
}

#nr1 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 1500px;
}

#nr2 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

link to working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Matthew_/86ptLzxm/3/

For more information on flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

I haven't done it in this example, but I would also recommend not using `float` to position your elements, but instead make use of `flexbox` functionality.

Comment: What is your intended layout for the link you posted?

Comment: yes but if i will have 1 div 100% width, next 25% 50% 25%, 1 div gray one schoudl have 100% widthmm but with flex box it have much less

Comment: take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/Matthew_/dh3nzjg7/2/. It is slightly different css, but uses flexbox to position 3 divs, 25%, 50%, and 25% with flexbox

Comment: ye it is really niece... but 1 div should have 100% and be on top.

Comment: see https://jsfiddle.net/Matthew_/dh3nzjg7/7/ for what you are looking for. All that you need to do is add an extra wrapper div

Comment: ou ye.. that make sense :D but if i will have a content it won't center it? or how to stop vertical center

Comment: if you read through the fliexbox link I included in my answer, it shows how to center content both vertically and horizontally

Comment: i using already existing flex box class.. that why my content was centered, just add style to html and unset align-items, and everything work xD thanks for your patient:D